# Bootstrap DateRangePicker - how to apply date change

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I'm adding a little extra logic to the daterangepicker (http://www.daterangepicker.com/). I have some simple code to the start date when a dropdown is selected.

The date does seem to change in the background, but only becomes visible when I close the picker and open it again. I'd rather the dates update immediately. Any idea if there's a way to "refresh" the shown dates to match when `setStartDate` is called?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way, looking through the functions available. You can call the "updateView()" method to have the view change as needed. Sorted.

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').data('daterangepicker').updateView();
```